# Updating autolayout constraints depending on orientation

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, screen-orientation

I have a `ViewController` class that has a `textField` variable, which is configured
when it is set in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var textField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            textField.delegate = self
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Text"
            view.addSubview(textField)
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.80, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField = UITextField()
    }
}
```

A set of auto layout constraints are added to the view. I want this text field
be centered in the middle (`.CenterX` and `.CenterY`), to be 80% (5%) the width (height)
of the `ViewController`'s `view` calculated in **portrait** mode.

If the device's orientation (`UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation`) is rotated into
landscape orientation, or presented from a landscape orientation, I want the width (height)
to remain the same as that for portrait orientation.

Changing the `attribute` for the `toItem` in:

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0))
```

to:

```
attribute: (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) ? .Height : .Width)
```

Doesn't do the trick as I guess the `textField` isn't getting (re)set when the device switches orientation.
Furthermore, this check seems a bit clumpy for Swift. Am I missing a trick with autolayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem in your code is that you did not set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of textField to `false`, 
whenever you want to use auto-layout constraints then you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of a view to `false`.

I have updated your code have a look and its working fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {    
    weak var textField: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            textField.delegate = self
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Text"
            view.addSubview(textField)
            // to see the size of textField
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

            textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.80, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField = UITextField()

    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex Your welcome, If you want more easy way to deal with programmatically constraint then have a look -https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster

Comment: I'm still not sure if specifying constraints in a relative percentage factor is a better approach? Therefore, your subviews are independent of iPhone model, say. I guess this similar in a way to CSS. Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: In context of all device iOS, It's not to bad. It will help a lot. but the thing is that how you are dealing with constraints. it's a way by which you can add a  percentage based constraints. same as CSS eg. a div have 20% height or width.

Comment: your subviews are indirectly independent of iPhone model, all subviews are dependent on their superView and the top most superview of the View hierarchy is window. and window size is always equal to iPhone size

Comment: A better approach to increase or decrease size of a view should be base on the percentage factor of device screen size, not it's superView. and it also depends on our requirement

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get the fixed coordinate bounds of the screen (iOS >= 8) and adjust the first two constraints appropriately:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Text"
        view.addSubview(textField)

        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        textField.textAlignment = .Center

        let fixedScreenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 0.8*fixedScreenBounds.width),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 0.05*fixedScreenBounds.height),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            ])
    }
}
```

Also, be aware that, since you are creating the textfield in code and you want to use autolayout, you must set its translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.